# Moving std::thread and maintaining state

Tags: c++, stdthread, move-constructor

I have a class which maintains a worker thread. It needs to be move constructible as I pass them around and add/remove from arrays, such as:

```
    for (...) {
        Foo foo;
        foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
    }
```

The class setup looks like this:

```
Foo::Foo() : worker(), working(true) {
    worker = std::thread(&Foo::work, this);
}

Foo::Foo(Foo &&foo) {
    working = true;
    worker = std::move(foo.worker);
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    if (worker.joinable()) {
        working = false;
        worker.join();
    }
}

void Foo::work() {
    while(working) {
        std::cout << "working..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

The problem is that after a `Foo` has been moved, its worker thread exits. I discovered it's because `working` is now seen by the `worker` to be `false`.

How can I get the `worker` thread to see the instance variables of the new (moved-to) parent `Foo` object? Is this possible? Is my move constructor totally wrong?

Comment: Well, you're getting Foo destructor  called, aren't you?

Comment: Basically, on move you should render `foo` into some inoperable state, so destructor won't do anything

Comment: You're binding the thread to a specific instance by passing `this` as an argument and calling a member function of that particular object. Therefore, moving the thread won't be as trivial as moving its handle.

Comment: You can move the thread to a new object but isn't the `this` pointer the thread was constructed with still pointing to the old object?

Comment: A very easy solution is to put the whole state including the thread in an object on the heap, and storing only a `unique_ptr` to that in `Foo`.

Comment: Your thread is basically running one of the methods of a specific object. You can't just magically have it start running the same method of a different object.